# Testing my sorting algorithm Error: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, integer

I would like to run this to see if it works. It is supposed to sort an table of integers, but I don't know how the main function is supossed to look like. How do I enter *tab into the function?

```
void    swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int buffer;

    buffer = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = buffer;
}

sort_int_tab(int *tab, int size)
{
    int a;
    int z;

    z = 0;
    while(z < size)
        {
            a = 1;
            while(a < size)
                {
                    if(tab[z] >= tab[a])
                        {
                            swap(&tab[z], &tab[a]);
                        }
                        z++;
                }
        }       a++;
        z++;
}

int main(void)
{
    
    sort_int_tab();
    return ();
}
```

Comment: `sort_int_tab` doesn't have a return type?

Comment: So I need to add a return type? Sorry, I am new to this. I understood the concept of the sorting, but I can't test it.

Comment: Yes, this code isn't standards compliant and only compiles because of legacy reasons. It will produce warnings if you have warnings enabled on your compiler(which is an extremely good idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important issues in your code. First, your function does not have a return type. Since you are not returning anything, it should be `void`:

```
void sort_int_tab(int *tab, int size) {
    /// Your code...
}
```

Second, inside of main, you are calling the function without arguments. You should pass an array of int (remember to allocate memory and initialise it), and the size of the array:

```
sort_int_tab(tab, size);
```

You can initialize an array like this and then pass it to your function:

```
int tab [5] = { 3, 4, 1, 2, 5};
sort_int_tab(tab, 5);
```